# Get the parent key from a given deeper value in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript object something like this

```
var finalJson= {
 "music_instr" : {
    "keyboard" : "yamaha",
    "guitar": "seagull"
  },
  "cars" : {
    "honda": "accord",
    "toyota": "corolla"

}
```

now is there a way where I can pass in something like this in a function like

```
getRootKey("yamaha"); //this should return me "music_instr"
getRootKey("corolla"); // this returns me "cars"
```

I was able to get it using multiple iterations over the object, but I wanted to know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: You'll have to iterate. You could build an index to make the search faster but that would mean a long initial indexing.

Comment: For reference about what is JSON : http://json.org/ (this should make clear why I edited "JSON" out of your question)

Comment: A good implementation would not need multiple iterations over the object.  You could write a single iteration that would keep track of the parent chain while it was iterating so when it found the property value, it would already have the parent chain and could just get the value one level up that you want.  But, you will have to iterate once to find the original property value.